# Angular2 NgModel not getting value in Jasmine test

Tags: forms, angular, karma-jasmine

I am using template-driven forms in Angular 2, and I'm trying to develop them test-first. I've scoured this site and the rest of the internet and I've tried basically everything I can find (mainly bunches of tick() statements and detectChanges() everywhere in a fakeAsync) to get the NgModel attached to my input to pick up the value so it can be passed to my onSubmit function. The value of the input element sets properly, but the NgModel never updates, which then means the onSubmit function does not get the correct value from the NgModel.

Here's the template:

```
<form id="createWorkout" #cwf="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="showWorkout(skillCountFld)" novalidate>
  <input name="skillCount" id="skillCount" class="form-control" #skillCountFld="ngModel" ngModel />
  <button type="submit" id="buildWorkout">Build a Workout</button>
</form>
```

*Note: I know that the value sent the ngSubmit is going to cause the test to fail, but it means I can set a break point in the function and inspect the NgModel.*

Here's the Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SkillService} from "../model/skill-service";
import {NgModel} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-startworkout',
  templateUrl: './startworkout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./startworkout.component.css']
})
export class StartworkoutComponent implements OnInit {
  public skillCount:String;

  constructor(public skillService:SkillService) { }

  showWorkout(value:NgModel):void {
    console.log('breakpoint', value.value);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is the spec:

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {By, BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { StartworkoutComponent } from './startworkout.component';
import {SkillService} from "../model/skill-service";
import {Store} from "../core/store";
import {SportService} from "../model/sport-service";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {dispatchEvent} from "@angular/platform-browser/testing/browser_util";

describe('StartworkoutComponent', () => {
  let component: StartworkoutComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture;
  let element:DebugElement;
  let skillService:SkillService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    var storeSpy:any = jasmine.createSpyObj('store', ['getValue', 'storeValue', 'removeValue']);
    var stubSkillService:SkillService = new SkillService(storeSpy);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ StartworkoutComponent ],
      providers: [{provide:Store , useValue:storeSpy}, SportService, SkillService],
      imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StartworkoutComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('without workout', () => {
    let createWorkout:DebugElement;
    let skillCount:HTMLInputElement;
    let submitButton:HTMLButtonElement;
    beforeEach(() => {
      createWorkout = element.query(By.css('#createWorkout'));
      skillCount = element.query(By.css('#skillCount')).nativeElement;
      submitButton = element.query(By.css('#buildWorkout')).nativeElement;
    });
    it('has createWorkout form', () => {
      expect(createWorkout).toBeTruthy();
      expect(skillCount).toBeTruthy();
    });
    it('submits the value', fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'showWorkout').and.callThrough();
      tick();
      skillCount.value = '10';
      dispatchEvent(skillCount, 'input');
      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick(50);
      submitButton.click();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick(50);
      expect(component.showWorkout).toHaveBeenCalledWith('10');
    }));
  });
});
```

I'm sure I'm missing something basic/simple, but I've spent the past day combing through everything I can find with no luck.

## Edit:

I think maybe people are focusing on the wrong thing. I'm pretty sure at this point that I'm missing something basic about how ngForm and ngModel work. When I add

```
&lt;p>{{cwf.value | json}}&lt;/p>
```

into the form, it just shows {}. I believe it should show a member property representing the input. If I type into the field, the value does not change. Similar things happen if I try to bind to skillCountFld. So I think the basic form setup is incorrect somehow, and the test is never going to work until the input is correctly wired to the skillCountFld controller. I just don't see what I'm missing.

Comment: Why do you expect `toHaveBeenCalledWith(10)` if you pass `ngModel` in `showWorkout` function?

Comment: @Amy Blankenship, had a very similar issue with `NgModel`, while in the case of reactive forms module there was no problem with the bindings. [Figured out how to get around it which can probably be of any help to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52828052/4373584).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> There are a lot of tests at the Angular site that are successfully
>   setting this without waiting for whenStable https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/874243279d5fd2bef567a13e0cef8d0cdf68eec1/modules/%40angular/forms/test/template_integration_spec.ts#L1043

That's because all code in those tests is executed inside `fakeAsync` zone while you are firing `fixture.detectChanges();` within `beforeEach`. So `fakeAsync` zone doesn't know about async operation outside its scope. When you're calling `detectChanges` first time `ngModel` is initialized

```
 NgModel.prototype.ngOnChanges = function (changes) {
            this._checkForErrors();
            if (!this._registered)
                this._setUpControl(); //<== here
```

and gets right callback for input event

```typescript
NgForm.prototype.addControl = function (dir) {
  var _this = this;
  resolvedPromise.then(function () { // notice async operation
      var container = _this._findContainer(dir.path);
      dir._control = (container.registerControl(dir.name, dir.control));
      setUpControl(dir.control, dir); // <== here
```

inside `setUpControl` you can see function that will be called by `input` event

```typescript
dir.valueAccessor.registerOnChange(function (newValue) {
  dir.viewToModelUpdate(newValue);
  control.markAsDirty();
  control.setValue(newValue, { emitModelToViewChange: false });
});
```

1) So if you move `fixture.detectChanges` from `beforeEach` to your test then it should work:

```typescript
 it('submits the value', fakeAsync(() => {
   spyOn(component, 'showWorkout').and.callThrough();
   fixture.detectChanges();

   skillCount = element.query(By.css('#skillCount')).nativeElement;
   submitButton = element.query(By.css('#buildWorkout')).nativeElement;

   tick();
   skillCount.value = '10';
   dispatchEvent(skillCount, 'input');
   fixture.detectChanges();

   submitButton.click();
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(component.showWorkout).toHaveBeenCalledWith('10');
}));
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/NWqtnlcbR6FQwiZ1gpDQ?p=preview)**

But this solution seems very complicated since you need to rewrite your code to move `fixture.detectChanges` in each of your `it` statements (and there is also a problem with `skillCount`, `submitButton` etc)

2) As Dinistro said `async` together with `whenStable` should also help you:

```typescript
it('submits the value', async(() => {
  spyOn(component, 'showWorkout').and.callThrough();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    skillCount.value = '10';
    dispatchEvent(skillCount, 'input');
    fixture.detectChanges();

    submitButton.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.showWorkout).toHaveBeenCalledWith('10');
  })
}));
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pWZpa1257921xuI1lmfn?p=preview)**

but wait why do we have to change our code?

3) Just add `async` to your beforeEach function

```typescript
beforeEach(async(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StartworkoutComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  element = fixture.debugElement;
  fixture.detectChanges();
}));
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/bRR6qxrqj4cd8zP7iMi5?p=preview)**

Comment: Adding async to the beforeEach fixed it, thanks! I have no idea why the form as visible in the browser in Debug was affected by that, but clearly it was.

Comment: Adding async to beforeEach fixed my case, which was just the same as Amy's

Comment: still did nothing after I put it on the it() and adding async to beforeEach()

Answer (score 3):

I think `whenStable` should do the trick in your case:

```
it('submits the value',() => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        // ngModel should be available here 
    })
});
```

More information here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#when-stable

**EDIT:**
The `ValueAccessor` seems not to notice the change if you directly manipulate the value of the DOM-element. But it should notice, if you write the value directly with the `ValueAccessor`:

```
const skillCount= fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(NgModel));
const ngModel= skillCount.injector.get(NgModel);

ngModel.valueAccessor.writeValue('10')
```

Comment: I actually don't think that's the issue. When I put `{{skillCountFld.value}}` in a p on the screen (visible when you click the Debug button in Karma), it shows null even if you manually put a value in the field. Plus, there are a lot of tests [at the Angular site](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/874243279d5fd2bef567a13e0cef8d0cdf68eec1/modules/%40angular/forms/test/template_integration_spec.ts#L1043) that are successfully setting this without waiting for whenStable.  I'm inclined to the view I somehow am not getting my input set up properly, but I am not seeing what is wrong.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I think if you directly change the value of an input element like you do, the `valueAccessor` will not notice it and so, will not fire. I edited my answer with an approach that should definitely trigger the `valueAccessor`

Comment: That would not explain why the ngModel's value does not appear on the screen in the browser when you type into the control or why when you bind to `{{cwf.value | json }}` that has no content, not even a member representing skillCount. I think until that setup is correct, any tweaks to the test are red herrings.

Comment: what if the element is outside of the component e.g in content of modal? I have a component where it also gets the button of outside element which I couldn't get in the code coverage for some reason