# Angular 4 unit test form with two way bindings. Issues updating model from view

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous

I stumbled accross a weird issue. I'm performing unit test with template based form and two way bindings. Here is the test code:

```
describe('Template Forms Input', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
      declarations: [DummyFormsComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('DOM input value changes the component model', fakeAsync(() => {

    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DummyFormsComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const dummyInputDe = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    const dummyInputEl = dummyInputDe.nativeElement;

    dummyInputEl.value = 'Super dummy';
    dummyInputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h2')).nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('Super dummy');
  }));
});

@Component({
  selector: 'dummy-forms',
  template: `
    <form>
      <input name="title" [(ngModel)]="model.anotherDummyValue">
    </form>
    <h2>{{model.anotherDummyValue}}</h2>
  `
})
class DummyFormsComponent {

  model = { anotherDummyValue: '', date: '' };
}
```

And I cannot get the test to pass. The h2 is always empty. However. If I remove the `<form>` tag and keep only the input in the view. The test is passing.

I think I'm doing something wrong with the asynchronous behavior. Would someone have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

Faced a similar problem as you (*refer my Angular environment details below*), searched all the internet regarding unit testing `NgModel`. Finally I figured out that setting the value alone to the queried input (which is in fact bound via `NgModel`) is not enough. i.e. `dummyInputEl.value = 'Super dummy';`
and the `dispatchEvent('input')` in your case never gets the actual `NgModel` operation up and running.

#### Solution

To get around the problem, you instead have to get the *injected* `NgModel` instance from the bound `input` and set the value through its `valueAccessor` property via the `writeValue` method, ***before emitting the `'input'` event on the DOM native element***.

```
...
const ngModel = dummyInputDe.injector.get(NgModel);

tick();                    // <== Important to wait until stable before writing value

ngModel.valueAccessor.writeValue('Super dummy');
dummyInputDe.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

fixture.detectChanges();                   // <= force updates to the view


expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h2'))
  .nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('Super dummy');                // <= Viola!
...
```

Note that we had to supply the `tick` inside the `fakeAsync` before writing to the `NgModel` value accessor. Probably because the NgModel's accessor needs a portion of time to be ready before you can write a value on it (*feedbacks appreciated in this regard*).

While in the case of specs without the `fakeAsync` zone, the same scenario should be handled with a `fixture.whenStable()` resolved promise to get the required result.

---

*Note:*
On every topic regarding unit testing on the web, especially when `NgModel` was in question, this hasn't been mentioned anywhere. Not even the official Angular documentation. Not sure if the new Angular versions (*especially changes in the `FormsModule` implementation*) have forced this change.

---

#### Angular Environment Setup

- Angular                 `v5.2.0`
- Karma                   `v2.0.0`
- Jasmine (jasmine-core)  `v2.8.0`

Answer (score 0):

Try added component instance in your code. more over I dont see ngOnInit or constructor in your component.

component = fixture.componentInstance;

We normally do in below way

```
describe('EditComponent', () => {
  let component: EditComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditComponent>;
  let displayText: DebugElement;
  let editableText: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [ EditComponent, MockCkeditorComponent ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.text = 'test input in the editor';
    displayText = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.row'));
    editableText = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.editor-form'));
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
....
```

In the beforeEach declar your component.